# Can I retain FutureAccessList when build a release?

Tags: uwp

Every time I build a release, my FutureAccessList get reset and I lost all file history. I don't want this to happen. It slow down my development. Is there a way to avoid it?

I also wonder if the list will get reset when user update to a new version. I could not test it at the moment because of this issue ([It is necessary to use RequestDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync() to actually install an update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023286/it-is-necessary-to-use-requestdownloadandinstallstorepackageupdatesasync-to-ac)) which force me to do a full install for just an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid it?

No, there is no way to retain the FutureAccessList after you remove and re-install the app.

Comment: Do you mean building a publish build will also be considered re-install the app? Or is it triggered because of the WACK test which involve running the release build? I also want to know. Is it considered "re-install" when I just update the app to a newer version.

Comment: @Nick As you mentioned in your previous question, you removed your app and installed it again. In that scenario, the FutureAccessList won't be retained. If you just update the app to a newer version, that should keep the FutureAccessList.